# Перевод разницы во времени в часы PHP

Tags: php, дата, время, diff

```
$cometime = '2019-09-03 23:40:13';
$gotime = '2019-09-04 12:00:00';
```

Как посчитать разницу $gotime - $cometime в *(int)* часах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$cometime = '2019-09-03 23:40:13';
$gotime = '2019-09-04 12:00:00';
         //получаем разницу в секкундах            делим на 3600 получаем в часах с долями
$diff = (strtotime($gotime) - strtotime($cometime))/3600;

// выводим как есть
echo $diff; 

echo ' --> ';
//округляем 
echo round($diff);

//выводит
12.329722222222 --> 12

// https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php -  тут можно почитать про дополнительные опции округления, если надо
```